# utf8 characters as question mark in Mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8

when I am trying to insert these characters in my mysql:

```
\u2605
\u9f8d
\u738b
```

I get a question mark instead.
(I have set mysqli_set_charset to utf8)

But for other characters like

```
\u2122
```

I get the right symbol (TM)

I have already set my table to utf8_general_ci

How to get the right symbol? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Good lord, I figured why. Even if I changed the table encoding, The rows were still in latin1, just changed it to utf8mb4_general_ci